# PTR records with Windows DNS Server not working

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, reverse-dns

I am trying to create a PTR record on my domain (kentrosecafe.com.au) so that I can get reverse DNS lookups working. The DNS Server I am using is the Windows DNS server which is on a Wiindows 2012 Server VM that is hosted on Azure. I believe I have configured the DNS server correctly because if query my DNS server directly the reverse DNS lookup works. However if I use any other DNS server such as the query the Google public DNS the reverse lookup fails.

For example if I do an nslookup:

```
>nslookup 168.63.166.233 kt-ws02.cloudapp.net

Server:  UnKnown
Address:  138.91.34.179

Name:    kentrosecafe.com.au
Address:  168.63.166.233
```

I get the result I am expecting (ie the domain name). My DNS server is on kt-ws02.cloudapp.net.

However if I do:

```
>nslookup 168.63.166.233 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find 168.63.166.233: Non-existent domain
```

What could be the issue?

**EDIT:**
After doing some more investigation, it isn't possible to do get my ISP to set this up. It seems that on Azure cloud VM where I've currently got my mail server setup it isn't possible to create PTR records at the moment. It is a requested feature as found here: [Provide Reverse DNS (PTR records) for Virtual Machines](http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/217313-networking-dns-traffic-manager-vpn-vnet-/suggestions/3090834-provide-reverse-dns-ptr-records-for-virtual-mach)

There isn't really an answer to my post unfortunately. Thanks however to @Gryphius and @BillThor for the pointers.

Comment: Usually your IP provider has to create PTR records for you . You can only create PTR records yourself if you have DNS-Delegation for the IP range.

Answer (score 1):

`PTR` records need to be setup by the own of the IP address range.  Contact your ISP/network provider and have them create the necessary `PTR` record(s).  It is possible to have then delegated to your servers, but few ISPs will do so.